# how to convert from matlab file to dll

Tags: dll, matlab

I am using matlab 2009 -- I have .m file.

I want to convert it to dll file so i can use it in c++.

how can I do that,  someone told me to use the matlab compiler and is it free?

Comment: Definitely **not** free.

Comment: Octave is free http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

Answer (score 1):

First you need the compiler. Available from Mathworks [here](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/). Also, the compiler is not free for most people, a student version is available when bundled with other Mathworks products.

Mathworks provides a '[Free MATLAB Compiler Interactive Kit](http://www.mathworks.com/programs/techkits/techkit_compiler_response.html?ref=CO)' which provides walkthroughs covering the DLL and executable build process.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use MATLAB's [C/C++ API](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/bqoqnz0.html) to convert your source code to C++. All MATLAB's functions are accessible, but it's a pain to write this without good wrappers. It might be worth your while to purchase the compiler.